# Trouble whilst creating a while loop

Tags: c#

So i was given this question below to answer and I initially created a for loop to do this which worked fine but i was told i could also do it in a while loop which is what i am trying now however i am not sure where I've gone wrong in my code below as i'm getting a indexoutofrange exception.

**Question 4** -
Write a piece of software that compares two strings and outputs the number of characters in the same position.
E.g. “helloworld” and “worldhello” would output 2 as there are two l’s in the same positions
compare the strings below to calculate your answer.

String1 - "helloworld"
String2 - "worldhello"

My for loop code which works perfectly

```
        string string1 = "helloworld";
        string string2 = "worldhello";

        int list = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < string1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (string1[i] == string2[i]) 
            {
                list = list + 1;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(list);
```

Now this is my while loop code which isn't working

```
        string string1 = "helloworld"; 
        string string2 = "worldhello"; 
        int i = 0;
        int total = 0;
        while (i < string1.Length)
        {
            i++;
            if (string1[i] == string2[i])
            {
                total = total + 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: In the for loop, `i++` occurs after the loop processes.  Move it after your `if` block in the `while` loop.

Comment: Consider how a `for` loop works - there are three sections to it. When does each section run? How is that different than the `while` loop you have?

Comment: Thanks this is really strange as i tried this earlier on and it didn't work but i just tried it now and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there!

The third part of the for loop (`i++`) will run *at the end of* each iteration, so you should not put `i++;` as the first statement in the while loop version. You should put it as the last statement:

```
while (i < string1.Length)
{
    if (string1[i] == string2[i])
    {
        total = total + 1;
    }
    i++;
}
```

In general, a for loop of the form:

```
for (x ; y ; z) { w; }
```

can be written as a while loop like this:

```
x;
while (y) {
    w;
    z;
}
```

Comment: this will throw an exception if string2.Length < string1.Length

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and help my code is working now. Weirdly as i sad to ps2goat i tried this earlier on putting i++ after the if but it wasn't working but now it seems to be working.

Comment: Daniel is right i mentioned this to my lecturer and for the question it's not a problem but something worth noting.

Comment: @OwenHodgson you could always do while (i < minLength) where minLength = Math.Min(string1.Length, string2.Length);